# Onclick functionality

Tags: android, xml

**itemlistrow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/RestaurantPicImageLinearViewID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RestaurantNameID"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RestaurantDataLinearViewID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RestaurantPicImageLinearViewID" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/RestaurantNameID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/RestaurantTypeID"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="type"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/RestaurantTimeID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="time"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RestaurantButtonLinearViewID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/BuyButton"
                android:layout_width="81sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Buy" 
                android:textSize="15sp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ReserveButton"
                android:layout_width="81sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Reserve" 
                android:textSize="15sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/RestaurantPicImageLinearViewID"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**I am not getting any error but my onclick functionality not working**

**Previously before i added the widgets to the listview the onclick functionality was working 
but after adding them. I have problems with Onclick not working**

**Looks to me my java class is fine but my xml having some errors**

Comment: have you tried to figue out if the onClick is actually called if you click an item?

Comment: you also write list item click listener in onCreate() before list data getting from server.try it.

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" ... in the xml was the problem .. i needed to add that line.. now it works –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens due to focusability of Buttons in listitem layout.

Add below line to root layout of your ListView's Item layout.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in itemlistrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
```

Comment: It happens due to focusability of Buttons in listitem layout(child view takes focus instead of listview).If you got solution then just accept answer.